# Custom model field output formatting

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a model:

```
class Cat(models.Model):
   number = models.IntegerField(...)
```

How can I modify the output so that when I call `cat.number`, I transform it into str, and add two zeros at the beginning? (*12 -> "0012"*).

I cannot write a separate method/property to get this value, only `number` attribute of `cat` must be used.

Comment: You can rename your field to `_number`, and then define a property `number`?

Comment: i had such idea, but names must be similar :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a property.

```
class Cat(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(...)

    @property
    def number5c(self):
        return '{:05}'.format( self.number )
```

and then refer to `cat_instance.number5c` instead of `.number`. If you want to retain the name "number" then you need to rename the model field and also define a setter...

```
class Cat(models.Model):
    db_number = models.IntegerField(...)

    @property
    def number(self):
        return '{:05}'.format( self.db_number )
    @number.setter
    def number( self, value)
        # maybe raise an error here, if value is not int or str
        self.db_number = int( value)
```